# Finding duplicates based on values of specific keys from a list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, key

I have the following list of `dict` records, from which I need to extract all the duplicates (based on the `label`) and leave one per `label` in the original records. Also, when the items get removed by `label`, always remove the one with the `headings` value `True` over one with `headings` value `False`.

**Input:**

```py
records = [
    {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 300},
    {"label": "x", "headings": True, "key": 301},
    {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 302},
    {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 303},
    {"label": "y", "headings": False, "key": 304},
    {"label": "y", "headings": True, "key": 305},
    {"label": "z", "headings": True, "key": 306},
    {"label": "z", "headings": True, "key": 307},
]
```

**Output:** (duplicate items)

```py
[
    {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 300},
    {"label": "x", "headings": True, "key": 301},
    {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 302},
    {"label": "y", "headings": True, "key": 305},
    {"label": "z", "headings": True, "key": 306},
]
```

Comment: You must have accidentally forgotten to include your own attempt/code.

Comment: So. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: It is also strange that you consider for example `{"label":'z', "headings":True, "key":306}` to be the duplicate since it has the same `label` and `headings` values as the next dictionary (with `"key": 307`). Typically I would say the _duplicate_ is the one that comes _later_. Or is there some additional rule about which dictionaries to keep/remove that you did not mention?

Comment: Same for `{"label":'x', "headings":False, "key":300}`. Why do you treat that as the duplicate and not `{"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 303}`, even though the latter comes later in your `records` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left a few questions unanswered (see comments). You also did not provide your own code and any unexpected output/error you got with it, so we have nothing to work with/fix. This is bad form.

But I found this to be a fun exercise, so here is what I came up with:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Record(TypedDict):
    label: str
    headings: bool
    key: int


def remove_duplicates(records: list[Record]) -> list[Record]:
    # First, decide which records (by index) _not_ to remove.
    # Map labels to 2-tuples of (index, headings boolean):
    keep: dict[str, tuple[int, bool]] = {}
    for idx, record in enumerate(records):
        label, headings = record["label"], record["headings"]
        # We keep it, if this is the first time we see that label OR
        # we did encounter it, but this record's `headings` value is `False`,
        # whereas the previous one was `True`:
        if label not in keep or (not headings and keep[label][1]):
            keep[label] = (idx, headings)
    # Combine all indices we want to keep into one set for easy lookup:
    keep_indices = {idx for idx, _ in keep.values()}
    # Iterate over all record indices in reverse order
    # and pop the corresponding records if necessary:
    removed = []
    for idx in reversed(range(len(records))):
        if idx not in keep_indices:
            removed.append(records.pop(idx))
    return removed
```

The original list is mutated in-place, but a new list is created and returned from the removed dictionaries/duplicates. The algorithm creates a few helper-datastructures sacrificing a bit of memory, but should be fairly efficient in terms of time, i.e. approximately *O(n)* with *n* being the number of records.

To test it:

```py
...

def main() -> None:
    from pprint import pprint
    records = [
        {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 300},
        {"label": "x", "headings": True, "key": 301},
        {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 302},
        {"label": "x", "headings": False, "key": 303},
        {"label": "y", "headings": False, "key": 304},
        {"label": "y", "headings": True, "key": 305},
        {"label": "z", "headings": True, "key": 306},
        {"label": "z", "headings": True, "key": 307},
    ]
    removed = remove_duplicates(records)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    print("remaining:")
    pprint(records)
    removed.reverse()
    print("removed:")
    pprint(removed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
remaining:
[{'headings': False, 'key': 300, 'label': 'x'},
 {'headings': False, 'key': 304, 'label': 'y'},
 {'headings': True, 'key': 306, 'label': 'z'}]
removed:
[{'headings': True, 'key': 301, 'label': 'x'},
 {'headings': False, 'key': 302, 'label': 'x'},
 {'headings': False, 'key': 303, 'label': 'x'},
 {'headings': True, 'key': 305, 'label': 'y'},
 {'headings': True, 'key': 307, 'label': 'z'}]
```